# partial range requests from chrome causing error

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, jetty

I have tried to implement range request video playback on a system that has webservlet and UI, that sends the range request from chrome starting with bytes :0- to the backend dataserver. Now I have been sending the full stream as I was under the impression the jetty server handles the response range. I see it work for the first and second request but then fails as the next request has a range that is less than what the previous range was.

> (Request 1)   Range:bytes=0-
>     (Response 1)  Accept-Ranges:bytes
>                   Content-Length:6748748
>                   Content-Range:bytes 0-10005/6748748
>     (Request 2)   Range:bytes=6717440-
>     (Response 2)  Accept-Ranges:bytes
>                   Content-Length:6748748
>                   Content-Range:bytes 6717440-6718465/6748748
>     (Request 3) Range:bytes=3932160-
>     (Response 3) Accept-Ranges:bytes
>   Content-Length:6748748
>   Content-Range:bytes 3932160-3933185/6748748
>     (Request 4) Range:bytes=5701632- 
>     (Response 4) Fails -

Can anyone make sense of this? With short videos this does not occur, so is there some timeout issue but then why is the chrome request with a smaller range? This is what I specify in the headers but again do not explicitly send the bytes as requested as I thought jetty handles it.

```
   if(inputStream != null) {
       if (parameters.containsKey("Range")) {
                String range =parameters.get("Range").toString();
                String[] ranges = range.split("=")[1].split("-");
                final int from = Integer.parseInt(ranges[0]);
                if(parameters.containsKey("Content-Length")) {
                    int sLength = (int) parameters.get("Content-Length");
                    int to = 10005 + from;
                    if (to >= sLength) {
                        to = (int) (sLength - 1);
                    }
                    if (ranges.length == 2) {
                        to = Integer.parseInt(ranges[1]);
                    }
                    final String responseRange = String.format("bytes %d-%d/%d", from, to, sLength);
                    parameters.put("Responserange", responseRange);
                    } 

           }
```

EDIT:

My logs in the dataserver side show the following consistently with each request being handled:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException,
```

Added additional stack trace

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.close(IteratingCallback.java:427)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onClose(HttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onClose(SslConnection.java:217)
```

Comment: This smells like a bug.  Are you using DefaultServlet to serve the ranges from static resources?  or something custom?

Comment: Opened issue with your question (credited) at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2249

Comment: Technically it is a static resource in that it is from a stored file but the back end code delivers the entire stream to the webserver/webservlet. Could this not be some timeout issue?